# Отвергать, отрицать, отклонять, отказать

Tags: выбор-слова

How do these words:

```
oтвергать
отклонять
отказать
отрицать
```

line up with some common [English equivalents](http://www.englishgrammar.org/words-refuse-reject-decline-deny/):

```
refuse
decline
reject
deny (this is the most different of the 4)
```

My rough understanding is:

```
отказать + (verb) ~ decline to do something
отказать + (noun) ~ reject someone or refuse something
отвергать + (noun) ~ reject someone or refuse something
отклонять + (noun) ~ refuse something
отрицать + (noun) ~ deny something
```

However, I suppose there is overlap, like in English.

Are any of these 4 Russian words nearly interchangeable?

Are there other words that fit neatly into this category?

Some examples (interchangeable words in English marked with '/'):

```
I rejected/declined/refused his offer.
I refused/declined to speak to him.
I rejected his assumption.
I denied the allegations.
My manuscript was rejected.
She rejected me. (implying a romantic advance)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These verbs in Russian are used with different cases, in different word collocations and in different speech styles.

1. Отказываться-Отказаться + verb: refuse to do smth

   Он отказался убираться в квартире.
2. Отказываться-Отказаться от + noun (Genitive case): to refuse smth, to turn smth down, to deny

   Алексей отказался от сотрудничества.
3. Отказывать-отказать + noun (Dative case) + в (Prepositional case): refuse smth to smb

   Врач отказал ему в лечении.
4. Отвергать-отвергнуть + noun (Accusative case, smth or smb): reject сompletely, bookish, formal style.

   Ты отверг меня!

   Президент отверг идею проведения новых реформ.
5. Отклонять-отклонить (Accusative case, smth): decline, formal style, normally used in the collocations: "отклонить предложение", "отклонить жалобу", "отклонить рукопись", "отклонить статью", etc.

   К сожалению, наша фирма вынуждена отклонить предложение вашей компании по ряду причин.
6. Отрицать (Accusative case, smth): deny

   Подсудимый отрицает свою виновность.

I'm going to translate your sentences:

1. Я отклонил его предложение: you have to use "отклонил" here because it's a collocation in Russian: "отклонить предложение". You can also use "отверг", but it sounds quite agressive.
2. Я отказался говорить с ним: "отказаться" is the only verb you can use with an infinitive.
3. Я отверг его предположение: collocation "отвергнуть предположение".
4. Я отказался от заявления: collocation.
5. Моя рукопись была отклонена.
6. Он отказал мне.

Comment: Юлия, пожалуйста, не надо подписывать каждый свой ответ. Вам уже указывали на это другие пользователи.

Answer (score 0):

```
4. Я не признал обвинений
6. Он*а* отказала мне :)
```

Comment: Да, есть много вариантов, которые могут звучать гораздо лучше в этих выражениях чем четыре слова из списка, но все-таки "не признал" в этом списке нету. Да и сам ответ больше тянет на комментарий к вопросу или ответу RussianTeacher.

Comment: Это конечно не главный вопрос. Однако, я спросил "Are there any other words that fit neatly into this category?". Хочу знать, если эти примеры, которые я придумал, как-то не "принято" переводить с этими четырьмя словами.

Comment: Но согласен, что вот этот ответ больше тянет на коментарий.